# Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet:

Tags: xml, xslt, github, xsd

I am getting the above error in Firefox 32.0, in Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 I get a blank page but show page source displays the XML file (it is a schema).

The details are that this is a stylesheet that I am developing and when I reference it locally, it is working as expected. Adding the reference to the schema from the website copy causes this error.

The sylesheet is located http://www.mlhim.org/xmlns/mlhim2/2_4_5/ccd-description.xsl

An examples of the source schema files are here:              https://github.com/mlhim/specs/blob/2_4_5/2_4_5/examples/Care_CCD_245.xsd

They do not have the reference to the style sheet (yet) but adding:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.mlhim.org/xmlns/mlhim2/2_4_5/ccd-description.xsl"?>
```

to one of those schemas should display the problem.

I will add that the website is hosted by github and the full URL to the stylesheet is https://github.com/mlhim/mlhim.github.io/blob/master/xmlns/mlhim2/2_4_5/ccd-description.xsl But even using that I get an 'unknown error'.

I know that GitHub redirects www.mlhim.org to mlhim.org But changing the reference to not use the 'www' also gives me a network error.

Comment: Please provide an [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.  Also note that you'll want to reference the raw version of your XSLT file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlhim/mlhim.github.io/master/xmlns/mlhim2/2_4_5/ccd-description.xsl) not the GUI version listed in your question.  Finally, make sure you're serving the XSLT from the same domain as the file against which you wish to apply the XSLT.

Comment: The problem appears to be due to same origin policy violation.

Comment: Good, glad you found it.  You might want to add some details/explanation in an answer for the benefit of those that come later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by violation of the same origin policy. 
AFAICT there is no work around other than to insure that the XSLT file is available from the same domain as the source file.